# Bash: catch if job is finished

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bunch of jobs that should run simultaneously.

Each job has its afterjob.

Afterjobs should run one by one.

Afterjob may start only if its job is finished.

The first finished job should immediately invoke its afterjob.

All other jobs on complete should put their afterjobs in queue.

I am trying to put afterjobs in queue with task-spooler (tsp).
However, I don't know how to catch if job is finished.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Starting jobs and collecting their pids
job1 & job1_pid=$! &
job2 & job2_pid=$1 &
job3 & job3_pid=$1

# Catching if jobs are finished and put the afterjobs in queue
{wait $job1_pid && tsp afterjob1} &
{wait $job2_pid && tsp afterjob2} &
{wait $job3_pid && tsp afterjob3}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to chain the queuing of an *afterjob* immediately after the *job* execution:

```
job1 && tsp afterjob1 &
job2 && tsp afterjob2 &
job3 && tsp afterjob3 &
```

This one will only execute the afterjobs it their corresponding job has executed successfully (returned a 0 value to environment). If you want the afterjob to always execute, you should use (thanks to MatthewStory for the suggestion):

```
{ job1; tsp afterjob1 } &
{ job2; tsp afterjob2 } &
{ job3; tsp afterjob3 } &
```

Comment: this will only execute if the `job` executes and completes successfully. `{ job; tsp afterjob1; } & { ... }` would be more equivalent to `wait`. Also the OP wants the after jobs to run one at a time.

Comment: I've never expected to make it work with such a tiny amount of lines.
And it works perfectly

Comment: I suddenly realized that there are also after-after-jobs. And after-after-jobs should run one by one. When I try  :  
`job1 && tsp afterjob1 && tsp afterafterjob1 &  
job2 && tsp afterjob2 && tsp afterafterjob2 &  
job3 && tsp afterjob3 && tsp afterafterjob3`  
it doesn't work, cause task spooler can't run two separate queues.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flock` to synchronize the after jobs.

Complete example:

```
#! /bin/bash

case "$1" in
  job1) echo job1; exit;;
  job2) echo job2; exit;;
  job3) echo job3; exit;;
  afterjob1) sleep 1; echo afterjob1; exit;;
  afterjob2) sleep 1; echo afterjob2; exit;;
  afterjob3) sleep 1; echo afterjob3; exit;;
esac

touch /tmp/afterqueue

{ "$0" job1; flock /tmp/afterqueue "$0" afterjob1; } &
{ "$0" job2; flock /tmp/afterqueue "$0" afterjob2; } &
{ "$0" job3; flock /tmp/afterqueue "$0" afterjob3; } &

wait

rm /tmp/afterqueue
```

Comment: Could you explain more, why do you use case statement?

Comment: `flock` works only with programs but not with Bash functions. In order to run the jobs and afterjobs in separate programs, the script calls itself (`"$0"`) with the name of the job as an argument. The case statement does the dispatching. If the jobs and afterjobs are already organized in separate files, you can remove the case statement and call them directly. I did it this way, to be able to put all code in just one example file.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sem`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/sem.html) command of [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) can also be used to synchronize jobs.

```
#! /bin/bash

case "$1" in
  job1) echo job1; exit;;
  job2) echo job2; exit;;
  job3) echo job3; exit;;
  afterjob1) sleep 1; echo afterjob1; exit;;
  afterjob2) sleep 1; echo afterjob2; exit;;
  afterjob3) sleep 1; echo afterjob3; exit;;
esac

{ "$0" job1; sem --id afterqueue "$0" afterjob1; } &
{ "$0" job2; sem --id afterqueue "$0" afterjob2; } &
{ "$0" job3; sem --id afterqueue "$0" afterjob3; } &

sem --id afterqueue --wait
```

But be aware of passing the citation ritual before you use any `parallel` command:

```
parallel --citation
```